# Absolute positioning browser resize for single page

Tags: html, css

I am working on a webpage form using the gravity forms plugin, however would like to the form to be styled in a particular manner. I have used absolute positioning for each individual field of the form, but ideally would like to keep the page layout the same (as in full) regardless of browser size, and would like this to occur for this page only.

The problem is that when i resize the window the layout of the page becomes distorted and everything is out of order, how can i stop the page from doing this?

```
    body .gform_wrapper .gform_body .gform_fields #field_42_1.gfield         .gfield_label 
    {
    position: absolute;
left: 80px;
top: 300px;
    }

    body .gform_wrapper .gform_body .gform_fields #field_42_1.gfield         .ginput_container
    {
    width: 33%;
    position: absolute;
left: 79px;
top: 325px;
    }

    body .gform_wrapper .gform_body .gform_fields #field_42_2.gfield         .gfield_label 
    {
    width: 45%;
    position: absolute;
left: 80px;
top: 355px;
    }

    body .gform_wrapper .gform_body .gform_fields #field_42_2.gfield         .ginput_container 
    {
    width: 33%;
    position: absolute;
left: 79px;
top: 380px
    }

    body .gform_wrapper .gform_body .gform_fields #field_42_10.gfield         .gfield_label 
    {
    width: 45%;
    position: absolute;
left: 740px;
top: 350px;
    }

    body .gform_wrapper .gform_body .gform_fields #field_42_10.gfield         .ginput_container 
    {
    width: 40%;
    margin-top: 10px !important;
    line-height:2;
    clear: both;
    position: absolute;
        left: 558px;
        top: 350px;
    }

    body .gform_wrapper .gform_body .gform_fields #field_42_4.gfield         .gfield_label 
    {
    width: 45%;
    position: absolute;
left: 80px;
top: 410px;
    }

    body .gform_wrapper .gform_body .gform_fields #field_42_4.gfield         .ginput_container 
    {
    width: 33%;
    position: absolute;
left: 79px;
top: 435px;
    }

    body .gform_wrapper .gform_body .gform_fields #field_42_5.gfield .gfield_label 
    {
    width: 45%;
    position: absolute;
left: 80px;
top: 465px;
    }

    body .gform_wrapper .gform_body .gform_fields #field_42_5.gfield         .ginput_container 
    {
    width: 33%;
    position: absolute;
left: 79px;
top: 490px;
    }

    body .gform_wrapper .gform_body .gform_fields #field_42_6.gfield         .gfield_label 
    {
    width: 45%;
    position: absolute;
left: 80px;
top: 520px;
    }

    body .gform_wrapper .gform_body .gform_fields #field_42_6.gfield         .ginput_container 
    {
    width: 33%;
    position: absolute;
left: 79px;
top: 545px;
    }

    body .gform_wrapper .gform_body .gform_fields #field_42_7.gfield .gfield_label 
    {
    width: 45%;
    position: absolute;
left: 80px;
top: 575px;
    }

    body .gform_wrapper .gform_body .gform_fields #field_42_7.gfield         .ginput_container 
    {
    width: 33%;
    position: absolute;
left: 79px;
top: 600px;
    }

    body .gform_wrapper .gform_body .gform_fields #field_42_8.gfield .gfield_label 
    {
    width: 45%;
    position: absolute;
left: 80px;
top: 630px;
    }

    body .gform_wrapper .gform_body .gform_fields #field_42_8.gfield         .gfield_description
    {
    width: 33%;
    position: absolute;
left: 80px;
top: 655px;
    }

    body .gform_wrapper .gform_body .gform_fields #field_42_8.gfield         .ginput_container 
    {
    width: 33%;
    position: absolute;
left: 79px;
top: 720px;
    }

    body .gform_wrapper .gform_body .gform_fields #field_42_9.gfield .gfield_label 
    {
    color: #2565ae;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 45%;
    position: absolute;
left: 558px;
top: 520px;
    }

    body .gform_wrapper .gform_body .gform_fields #field_42_9.gfield         .gfield_description
    {
    width: 40%;
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
left: 558px;
top: 570px;
    }

    body .gform_wrapper .gform_body .gform_fields #field_42_9.gfield         .ginput_container
    {
    width: 23%;
    position: absolute;
left: 558px;
top: 720px;
    }

    body #gform_wrapper_42 .gform_footer input[type=submit] 
    {
    position: absolute;
left: 558px;
top: 760px;
    }
```

Before resize: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hrD8.png
After resize: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULNR4.png

Comment: including a code snippet and an image of the issue may help others help you

Comment: you can media queries to make it responsive.

Comment: Hard to tell without any html or css but I would suggest to use a `position:relative`on form container and try to use every position and size in a percentile way

Comment: About your edit: And what could be the desired result? Everything smaller o smaller & stacking? Or something different. I think that @WisdmLabs point you in the right direction. Absolute positioning is like engrave in stone, not flexible or easily adaptable.